# Kubernetes homelab local storage options

Tags: kubernetes, cache, distributed-filesystems

**I think I have an XY problem, if you can identify it as one, please answer accordingly!**

### Background

My primary goal is to learn Kubernetes, with a closely-followed secondary goal of doing homelab stuff -- hosting a variety of small services for someone who should touch more grass.  With that, I have a coolberetes homelab cluster running K3S, a handful of worker nodes, a potato-powered cluster manager node, and a QNAP NAS as the backend storage.

The QNAP has 8x12TB 7200RPM drives in a RAID-6.  It is great at sustained transfers, but random IO makes it fall on its face.  This is expected due to the workload and the hardware.  The QNAP is on a 10gbit switch, with 2.5/1gbit ports to the workers, so there isn't a screaming amount of bandwidth, but I think it will be enough for what I want.  Each worker has a 1TB NVMe drive locally, which I think is relevant later.

### Problem

Some of the containers I'm running are applications that I did not build out, and as such cannot easily modify the design choices from the developer.  Please keep this in mind.

Most of the containers are split into two "classes" of volume: `data`, `config`. The `data` volumes are big bulk files, sequential access.  These I have been handling via NFS/SMB volume mounts, and this works fine.  The `config` volumes are things like a handful of YAML files, a JSON file or two, some logging folders, a SQLite database, etc. These volumes perform **much** worse when mounted via NFS, and the SQLite databases outright fail due to locking problems.

### Workarounds so far and why they were rejected

- "Put the config volumes on NFS" -- SQLite will cause crashes due to locking errors.  This is v3 & v4.
- "Stop using SQLite" -- The software in the images is hardcoded to use it.  Rewriting that isn't viable.
- "just put these config volumes on the local disk" -- how do purely-local volumes allow me to migrate or scale any services?
- "put the caches on the NAS" -- the QNAP won't let me add write caches for silly reasons
- "use rsync to sync the volume" -- yes, did that, worked "okay", doubt this is an official solution though.

### Expected solution

This is where I think my XY problem is, or at a minimum a complete lack of knowledge sits.  My expectation is there is a way to leverage the 1TB NVMe drives on each worker, with a block storage exported via the NAS, as a distributed or clustered filesystem.  I would expect I could mount this distributed/clustered filesystem locally, let the containers operate on it, and behind the scenes it will synchronize itself among the running nodes and back to the QNAP for backups. For what I'm doing, a 1TiB filesystem will fit what I need it to for the `config` volumes.

If this kind of solution exists, what is it called, and where can I learn more?
If this is the wrong solution, what is the "correct" one?

Comment: Alternate question: What are commonly-used OSS tiered storage solutions for Kubernetes in a clustered or distributed environment?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want a distributed storage solution that's intended for deployment in a cluster. I'm actually in the process of setting up something fairly similar with [Longhorn](https://longhorn.io/). Longhorn was a natural choice for me because I'm using K3s, which (as a Rancher product) has Longhorn integration built in, but it should be able to integrate with any Kubernetes distribution with a little more work.

Disclaimer: I haven't actually set this up yet, but I've done all the research and am ready to pull the trigger as soon as I get a few spare hours. My understanding is that it will manage the replication and synchronization of the physical data pretty much exactly as you described, and it [does support](https://longhorn.io/docs/1.5.1/snapshots-and-backups/backup-and-restore/set-backup-target/#set-up-nfs-backupstore) NFS/SMB as a backup target.

My only concern with this setup is performance: As I said I haven't set it up yet, so I don't know how it will shake out, but I know that Longhorn does synchronous replication (everything has to be written to the replicas before the write operation is considered "complete") so it will definitely be slower than purely-local NVMe. How much slower remains to be seen, but my guess is that this won't be a problem for you, especially over 10Gb networking, since you weren't concerned with e.g. the *performance* of SQLite over NFS, just the consistency problems.

I'll try to remember to post an update here once I get this set up (I'm planning on some time this week). I'll try to do some basic performance testing on local disk vs. Longhorn.

FWIW Longhorn is not the only option out there. Other names that have come up in my research include [Piraeus](https://piraeus.io/) and [Linstor](https://linbit.com/linstor/), but I haven't done much research on those so I don't know how they compare.

### Edit: Benchmark results

I've spent the day playing with `fio` and Longhorn in various configurations, and my conclusion is that it's workable but definitely not high-performance. It's fine for stuff that's mostly idle all the time (like self-hosted web apps), but if you wanted to run, say, a heavily-loaded relational database on it I'd probably recommend you try something else.

I ran 3 tests (well, 6, because I did read and write separately) against each configuration I tested. The tests were as follows:

- Max bandwidth: 4MiB reads/writes from a single process at a queue depth of 16
- Max IOPS: 4k random reads/writes from 16 parallel processes, each running at a queue depth of 16 (so 256 operations outstanding at a time)
- An attempt at simulating a more "real-world" workload for the situation we're discussing: 4k random reads/writes from a single process at a queue depth of 2. My intent with this is to mimic e.g. a lightly-loaded web app backed by SQLite (which uses 4k pages by default IIRC.)

I ran these tests in the following situations:

- Directly against the local disk, with no virtualization
- Against the same disk, but mounted into a pod with `hostPath`
- Against the same disk via Longhorn with 1 replica

  - From a local pod (running on the same node as the replica)
  - From a remote pod (running on a different node than the replica)
- Against the same disk via Longhorn with 2 replicas (I only have 2 nodes in the cluster at the moment, so it wouldn't be very meaningful to test 3 replicas.)

Servers were running Epyc 7262s (8c16t), 64G RAM, and were connected via 10GbE. The disks being tested were SK Hynix Platinum P41s (rated for 7000MiB/s read, 6500 MiB/s write, and ~1.5M IOPS)

The tables are a bit confusing so to clarify, rows represent storage configurations (e.g. testing directly against the drive vs. testing via Longhorn or whatever), and columns represent workloads. The "BW - R" column refers to the read workload targeting max throughput, the "IOPS - W" column refers to the write workload targeting max IOPS, etc.

##### Results - Throughput (MiB/s)

|  | BW - R | BW - W | IOPS - R | IOPS - W | Light - R | Light - W |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Direct | 7025 | 6333 | 5861 | 5584 | 174 | 143 |
| Host path | 7027 | 6196 | 4789 | 5515 | 117 | 405 |
| LH - 1R, local | 1512 | 354 | 118 | 67.2 | 19.6 | 19.1 |
| LH - 1R, remote | 244 | 254 | 84.3 | 40.5 | 11.2 | 11.7 |
| LH - 2R | 395 | 254 | 96.8 | 34.5 | 19.2 | 10.6 |

##### IOPS

|  | BW - R | BW - W | IOPS - R | IOPS - W | Light - R | Light - W |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Direct | 1756 | 1583 | 1.50M | 1.43M | 44.5k | 36.6k |
| Host path | 1.75k | 1.5k | 1.2M | 1.4M | 29.9k | 104k |
| LH - 1R, local | 377 | 88 | 30.1k | 17.2k | 5.0k | 4.9k |
| LH - 1R, remote | 61 | 63 | 21.6k | 10.1k | 2.8k | 2.9k |
| LH - 2R | 98 | 63 | 24.8k | 8.8k | 4.9k | 2.7k |

##### Latency

|  | BW - R | BW - W | IOPS - R | IOPS - W | Light - R | Light - W |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Direct | 9.1ms | 10.1ms | 170μs | 357μs | 44.4μs | 54.2μs |
| Host path | 9.1ms | 10.2ms | 208μs | 181μs | 65.9μs | 18.8μs |
| LH - 1R, local | 42.3ms | 181ms | 8.5ms | 14.9ms | 396μs | 408μs |
| LH - 1R, remote | 259ms | 252ms | 11.85ms | 25.1ms | 713μs | 680μs |
| LH - 2R | 162ms | 251ms | 10.3ms | 28.9ms | 406μs | 738μs |

Note on latency: I'm using the average `lat` number produced by `fio`, which I believe refers to the time from when the operation is submitted to when the read/write comes back as completed. That's why it's so high for the max-throughput scenarios: those are 1000x the size of the 4k operations so they're bound to take a while longer.

#### Takeaways:

Any way you slice it, you're sacrificing a *lot* of performance compared to what you get talking to a local disk with no virtualization.

But I'm not sure that matters! Especially if we look at the IOPS and latency numbers for the "light" workload, we can see that we're still getting >1k IOPS, and those operations are completing in <1ms. IMO that's fine for light everyday usage. If your webapp's database needs to hit the disk a few times to serve a request you're still not going to notice the difference, because anything under 1ms is absolutely *dwarfed* by network latency.

Where this would all start to fall apart would be if you needed to support significant load (which is, to be fair, sort of *expected* to be the case if you're running Kubernetes - it's definitely not designed with the homelabber in mind.) As soon as you hit a few thousand concurrent users you're going to *really* start feeling the pinch on those IOPS.

Longhorn [is working on](https://longhorn.io/docs/1.5.1/spdk/quick-start/) V2 of their storage engine which they claim "significantly reduces I/O latency while simultaneously boosting IOPS and throughput," but it's still under heavy development and doesn't yet support important features like snapshots and backups. Maybe once it's released I'll upgrade and re-do these benchmarks.

In the meantime, if you need more performance than Longhorn can give you, maybe Piraeus/Linstor (apparently Piraeus is built on top of Linstor) is worth a look? From what I'm reading it can do asynchronous replication, which is perfect for the scenario when you're only running 1 of any given thing at a time and just want the replication so that pods can bounce between nodes without having to worry.

Another option that I came across recently is [Vitastor](https://git.yourcmc.ru/vitalif/vitastor), which looks very interesting but is *very* much off the beaten path. Let me know if you do try it out though, I'm very curious to know how well it works.

Comment: Longhorn, Ceph, Gluster were the 3 things that kept showing up, and it took mere seconds before I would find the "XXX isn't suited for this workload" kind of posts.  Someone else diving in on Longhorn is great!  I don't necessarily need an NFS backend for the config volume, that's just easier for me right now.  I can carve out 1TiB of iSCSI or similar if I need to, or (maybe) even make the NAS part of the Longhorn cluster.

Comment: Making the NAS part of the Longhorn cluster is my planned solution, yes - I'm in a very similar situation to you, with a big spinning-rust pool for bulk storage and a set of 1TB SSDs (one per node) for fast storage. Originally I planned to expose the bulk storage via NFS/SMB or iSCSI, but after reading the longhorn docs it looks like it will be perfectly happy with a storage pool that has only one replica and exists on a particular node (namely, the one with the spinning disks). Then you can use tags to distinguish between your slow and fast pools.

Comment: @BryanBoettcher Updated my answer with benchmarks. Short version: Longhorn is probably fine for homelab usage but there are almost certainly more performant options out there.